# Passing Json status code in Springboot+Angular

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot

Is there any way to pass a Json status/response from Springboot to Angular service? Let’s say, beside the Httpstatus sent on Response Entity, I want also to send a Json response. Thanks

Or maybe a second question is how to use the Http status from Spring boot, in Angular service.

Answer (score 0):

From your springboot endpoint, you can send JSON response along with the HttpStatus
Below is the sample code

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getUserDetails" , produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getUserDetails(){

userDetails = userService.getUserDetails();
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userDetails);
}
```

This is how you can return userDetails object which will be converted to JSON automatically as we used produces = "application/json"